# Sample estimators with big data - should I estimate the standard deviation?

Tags: statistical-significance

Reading about sample statistics I found that there are some that you use when the SD of the populations are unknown.

However, (assuming the SD of both populations are the same), if your sample size is big enough, can't you just estimate the standard deviations from the samples? Or is that dangerous?

Comment: You can and should estimate parameters from samples (at least when following the classical "frequentist" approach to statistics). Those are going to be only estimates for the true (unknown) parameters. What particular hypothesis test are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking of is doing a t-test when the variance is unknown instead of a z-test when the variance is known. If you know the variance, it's better to use the z-test. However, it sounds like you want to say that, since you have such a tight estimate of the standard deviation when you have many observations, you can say that you have the population parameter pinned down.

Well...even then, you don't actually know the population variance. Howeer, the t-test takes care of this internally. As you increase the degrees of freedom for the t-distribution by having a larger and larger sample size, the t-distribution converges to N(0,1). For a large sample size when you almost know the population variance, you're almost doing the z-test.